# How do you prevent mold in CamelBak hydration bladders?

Tags: cleaning, hydration-bladders, mold

When using a CamelBak (or other hydration bladder system), it is easy for mold to grow if the bladder is left sitting with water in it. What is the best way to avoid mold (or other nasties) growing inside in between trips?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CamelBak have a great [answer](https://www.camelbak.com/en/customer-service/help-center/care-cleaning/product-cleaning/how-to-clean-reservoir) in the help section of their website. Summarising their recommendations:

Keep it clean and dry when not in use. If mould develops:

- Use hot water and two tablespoons of baking soda or bleach
- Leave for about 30 minutes
- Wash with hot water and mild soap
- Air dry

Comment: This does work and extends the life well, but I feel it just delays the inevitable. I usually replace the bladder after 3 or 4 years when the bleach just isn't keeping it at bay any more.

Comment: I would add to make sure to hang it where water will run out and it will dry.  You can put the bite valves through most dishwashers to get them thoroughly clean as well.

Answer (score 9):

I clean it out then leave it to dry for a day or two. But you can never seem to get all of the water out of the hose, so I keep mine in the freezer. At -18 the mold can't grow.

Comment: I leave mine hanging upside-down for a day or so, and any remaining water collects near the bite valve. A quick pinch & shake helps get rid of this water.

Answer (score 8):

Leave the filler cap open to allow any water residue inside to evaporate and so the humidity level of the air inside the bladder matches that of the air in the environment around it

Comment: This is basically what I've done for nearly 20 years with my platypus.  May also want to take off the bite-valve on the straw so the straw has airflow through it.

Comment: I tuck a half of a paper towel inside next to the filler cap to wick away and dry that crease.

Answer (score 4):

This is why I like the pouches that have a zip-lock bottom as well as a cap on the top - it makes it a lot easier to clean the inside and leave it open to let it fully dry.

My friend also swore by leaving the pouch in the freezer when not in use - this would obviously slow down mould growth considerably in between uses.

Answer (score 4):

I used a blow dryer on low setting to dry the bag and tub, and a paper towel pouch (twist tie close) with rice - I figure if it gets moisture out of a cell phone and salt - it ought to work for a Camelback. I also save the little silica gel packets that come in vitamin bottles and new shoe boxes and may try those.

Answer (score 4):

I just get it mostly dry and then pop it in the freezer until the next use. This keeps anything from growing and takes 30 seconds and no cost.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest:

- leaving the cap open, letting it air dry,
- then sealing it up and *keeping it out of direct sunlight* in a dark area (perhaps inside your pack).
- When you are ready to use it again, *rinse it a few times* - run some water through the hose as well.

Answer (score 3):

I get food-grade 3% hydrogen peroxide (NOT 35%) from my health-food/ vitamin store and put a cap-ful in any water container then fill it to the brim. It works really well to kill microbes of all kinds by oxygenating the water, and you can drink it in that low of a concentration (it is used in commercial food preparation, and some people believe that drinking oxygenated water is actually good for you as well).

Answer (score 1):

I use a [reservoir dryer](https://www.rei.com/product/753378/camelbak-reservoir-dryer) to hang my reservoir open and upside-down, and...

- Only ever fill with water
- Empty and dry every night, even if using it the next day
- After about half an hour of drying pinch the bite valve and shake to remove any extra water, and also shake the reservoir with the opening facing down to remove any water that has collected
- Pack it all away after about a day, or once things look nice and dry

I've been following this approach with the reservoir for the CamelBak I bought in 2005 is still going strong, with no mould or other nasties inside!